# Coinpayments IPN is not redirecting user back

Tags: callback, paypal-ipn, coinpayments-api

The code:

```
$CP->setFormElement('currency', 'LTCT'); 
$CP->setFormElement('amountf',0.0002);   
$CP->setFormElement('item_name', 'Test Item');  
$CP->setFormElement('custom', 'customValue235');  
$CP->setFormElement('ipn_url', 'http://middleman.pw/CoinPayments-master/callback.php');
```

I still just get the following:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/91094867c04a69adf3d358dc7b147e90.png]

Just to clarify, the user won't be redirected back to my website.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: transaction details is not coming after successful checkout

Comment: It seems that there is some piece of the last sentence missing, the user should be redirected back to... where?

Comment: i am quite confused with IPN file and URL.

Answer (score 0):

IPN is for Instant Payment Notification
To redirect user after successful payment, use

```
$CP->setFormElement('success_url', 'http://middleman.pw/CoinPayments-master/callback.php');
```

From https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc-create-transaction , success_url   Sets a URL to go to if the buyer does complete payment. (Only if you use the returned 'checkout_url', no effect/need if designing your own checkout page.)